# “To be XML serializable types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object)” error when DeSerializing XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I upgraded web application/solution from .NET 3.5 to  4.5.2. And run into issues with De-serializing XML into an object (no compilation issues). The previous versions of the application worked without issues for the last 12 years, since .Net 2.0.  At run time, the CallStack shows below errors. After extensive googling it seems to be I have to add Add() , but I can’t figure out in what capacity and where and why did it stop working after upgrading to .NET 4.5.2. Adding empty Add(object obj) to Map and/or MapEntry did not do a trick. I spend many many hours and appreciate any help!!!

> [InvalidOperationException]: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator does not implement Add(System.Object). 
>   [InvalidOperationException]: There was an error reflecting field mapItems
>   [InvalidOperationException]: There was an error reflecting type Framework.Common.Configuration.StructuredSettings.Map
>   [InvalidOperationException]: There was an error reflecting type Framework.Reporting.ReportConfig

```
    public class StructuredSettings 
    {
        public class Map  
        {
            public Map() {}
            public Map (params StructuredSettings.MapEntry[] items)
            {
              mapItems = items;
             }

           public MapEntry[] mapItems;
         }


         public abstract class MapEntry : IComparable
        {
           public MapEntry() {}
           protected MapEntry(string key) { m_Key = key;}

           // IComparable implementation
           public int CompareTo(object obj)
           {
               MapEntry party = obj as MapEntry;
              if (party == null)
                 throw new ArgumentException("Bla Bla", "obj");
             return String.Compare(m_Key, party.m_Key);
           }
        }

    //trying to de-serialize the XML into object. Get errors here at run time
    public static XmlSerializer        GetMapInstanceXmlSerializer(StructuredSettings.TypedTarget target) 
    {
         XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

         attrOverrides.Add(typeof(StructuredSettings.Map), "mapItems",
         GetArrayAttributes(target.MapItemType, target.ItemElementName));

         XmlAttributes rootAttrs = new XmlAttributes();
         rootAttrs.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(target.FieldElementName);
         attrOverrides.Add(typeof(StructuredSettings.Map), rootAttrs);

         return  new XmlSerializer(target.FieldType, attrOverrides);
        }

       }


       //Report Configuration is being initialized at run time, but break point                 never stops here 
    public class ReportConfig : StructuredSettings.MapEntry
    {
       public ReportConfig()
       {
         //original code does not have a constructor, but i tried adding to no     vail
       }

       [XmlAttribute("Title")]
       public string m_Title;

       //many other attributes go here

       [XmlElement("RenderingInfoWrap")]  
       public XmlDocument m_xmlRenderingInfo;

       public XPathNodeIterator RenderingInfoNodeSet
       {
          get
          {
             if (m_xmlRenderingInfo == null)
            return null;

            return new XPathDocument(new                     XmlNodeReader(m_xmlRenderingInfo)).CreateNavigator().Select(@"*[1]"); 
            }
          }
         }
```

//

  
    
      
        30,31,32
      
    
    
      
        31
        
        
        MyUserName
        HO Consultant
      
      
        30,32
        
        
        
        HO Consultant
        
          HO_Consultant..fw_HOCList
          Always
          -1
          (all)
        
      
      
        
          
          
        
      
    
    
      
        HO_Consultant..rpt_InventorySummaryMultiHOC
      
      
      
      
    
    
      
        
        
          HO Consultant
        
        
          Total Opened
        
        
          Total Closed
        
        
          Total Past Diary
        
        
          Total Incurred
        
      
    
            }

Comment: If you read my last comment, forget it, just add [XmlIgnore] attribute to RenderingInfoNodeSet and it will work. :P

Comment: Thank you, Gusman! Adding [XmlIgnore]  right before - public XPathNodeIterator RenderingInfoNodeSet - seems to help to get read of the exceptions. But wouldn't using [XmlIgnore] ignore this attribute? I am trying to de-serialize the XML and  <RenderingInfoWrap>  is needed child?  Thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: No, it's not needed, look, you already have the attribute [XmlElement("RenderingInfoWrap")]  on m_xmlRenderingInfo, and the RenderingInfoNodeSet property just uses that field for returning some content from it, so no, it's not needed.

Comment: And if you're curious about why it worked and now it doesn't, well, the old version of the serialization saw that your property had no setter so it ignerd it, and now ot seems that the serializer first checks for types of properties and checks the setters after that, because this is why it stopped working.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gusman! Really appreciate the help.